# How do I get rid of cosmetic overrides?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape (3) I've chosen a cosmetic override for my weapon, whenever I am wearing one, but now I want to get rid of it, so it shows the weapon I'm actually wearing. 
For example, I chose something, then changed it to Mazcab Poker for convenience. I have tried both the 'Revert' option and 'Apply', but neither works. I still see the same 'sword' when I equip something.

How can I reset this?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/runescape/comments/2qnp6i/how_do_i_remove_my_cosmetic_overrides/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the cosmetic item in your Wardrobe and click "deactivate"/

Revert/Apply is used for testing overrides (i.e, not for overrides that are currently used)